# Spark caching: fraction cached 100% while size on Disk is not zero, why?

Tags: apache-spark

I am calling `cache()` on a DataFrame, and i think that it is fully cached successfully, because in Spark UI i can see the Frsction Cached field in the Storage tab is 100%. But at the same time I see that the Size on disk is not zero.

Note that I have enough memory in the cluster (>60GB), and the DataFrame size is 37GB, but I see that 4.7GB are saved on disk.

Here is a screen shot of what I see:

[image]

I wonder why/when this scenario happens?

P.S. I am using Spark 2.0.0 on EMR 5.0

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment. My first comment was if you have allocated enough memory to Spark. Now, can you try `persist(MEMORY_ONLY)` and see if there's a difference in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unlike RDDs, Datasets (and I guess, DataFrames too) have the default persist as `MEMORY_AND_DISK`.

Here's the source code : [Dataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2714)

Thanks for asking the question. I didn't know that. :D

Answer (score 1):

When you use persist method, you can specify the StorageLevel as an argument.

But when you are using cache method it will use the storageLevel as MEMORY_AND_DISK.

Please refer link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Neeraj